# ERROR: Could not convert date and/or time from string data type

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

We are trying to convert a string field to a date field using the CAST function in Marketing Cloud. Our goal is to confirm that people have not made a purchase in the last 7 days, in fact from 5pm one day until 5pm 7 days later
Below's the SQL code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Pedidos_NoHechos_DE
WHERE (OrderAccountId IS NULL 
OR (ISDATE(OrderCreatedDate) = 1 
AND 
CAST(OrderCreatedDate AS DATETIME) >= 
DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME))) 
AND 
CAST(OrderCreatedDate AS DATETIME) < 
DATEADD(HOUR, 17, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)) 
AND OrderTotalAmount = 0))
```

Comment: Please update your question to include an example of the date string you're trying to convert.